# Keyboard Shortcuts for chrome extension can be seen in chrome://extensions/shortcuts but not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is a chrome extension which clears the input fields of the webpage. it works perfectly fine when I click at the extension.

I tried to give a keyboard shortcut to it. it was working at first but next day when I opened chrome extension was not there(maybe because I kept my extension in my chrome's profile folder at `/home/user/.config/google-chrome/Profile 3/Extensions/`). so chrome might have not recognised and removed it because it's not from store.

I added it again but this time keyboard shortcut was not working. I don't have any knowledge of developing extensions. I just looked up at the google.developer guides and created this.

```
// manifest.json
{
  "name": "Reset Answers",

  "description": "Resets checkboxes, radio button, Input Text!",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
  "action": {},
  
  "commands": {
    "_execute_action": {
      "suggested_key": "Alt+C",
      "description": "clears input fields"
    }
  },

  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/icon16.png",
    "48": "/images/icon48.png",
    "128": "/images/icon128.png"
  }
}
```

```
// background.js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    func: clear,
  });
});

function clear() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].type == "text" || elements[i].type == "number") {
      elements[i].value = "";
    } else if (elements[i].type == "radio" || elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
      elements[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
}


chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {

});
```

I tried calling `clear` function inside that event listener function is also not working.

`chrome://extension/shortcuts` page shows the extension and the shortcut like this but its not working.
[image]

`Alt+C` is not being used for any other keyboard shortcut on my pc. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Because the callback of chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener is empty.

Comment: Works for me in Chromium Version 106.0.5249.103 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-Bit), on Manjaro Linux with XFCE. Do you see any error messages in the console?

Comment: for some reason `Alt + C` was not working, idk why. this combination is not bind to any of the shortcuts. but I changed the key and its now working

Comment: @NorioYamamoto we don't need to call the function in this case because this shortcut is not for to run the function, but to activate the extension

Comment: @Asmit What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Asmit "but I changed the key and its now working" Which keyboard shortcut are you using now?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 22.04, I changed it to `Alt + V` now its working, It was working with `Alt + C` too but only if I go to `chrome://extensions/shortcuts` and set it to `Alt + C`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain operating system and Chrome shortcuts (e.g. window management) always take priority over Extension command shortcuts and can not be overwritten.

The following sample outputs to console.log when Ctrl+Shift+1 is entered.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "commands": {
    "command1": {
      "suggested_key": "Ctrl+Shift+1",
      "description": "hoge"
    }
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((c) => {
  switch (c) {
    case "command1":
      console.log("command1");
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks, for some reason `Alt + C` combination was not working. and I am sure that this combination is not used by any other thing in my pc I also mentioned this in the post. I used other combination and now its working